# Showing Recent Messages Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SFAuthenticationSession

Tags: swift, sfauthenticationsession, mac-catalyst

I've just updated to macOS Catalina and on xCode to test an app I was building for iOS on how it'll look like on mac I checked `Mac` under Development Info.

[image]

When I run it on an iOS device it runs successfully. But when I run it using My Mac as target it gives an error:

> Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SFAuthenticationSession

Here is a full picture of the error:
[image]

Comment: just ran into the same issue. any luck?

Comment: I haven't found the solution but I know it is because of Pods. So I'm assuming that some pods that I've are not supported for MacOS. I've tried it with XCode v11.1 and after updating pods to their latest versions.